# Modification of matching

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, random-matrices, discrete-mathematics, random-graphs

Suppose i have an $n \times n$ random bipartite graph and suppose that i repeat the following process $n$ times. At the start (stage 1) each edge is selected independently with probability $p(n)$, and we output the largest matching $\mathcal{M}_{1}$. In stage 2 all edges are selected randomly again regardless of how they appeared before but this time we take the largest matching $\mathcal{M}_{2}$ which doesn't include any of the edges of $\mathcal{M}_{1}$ (alternatively we could assume the edges of $\mathcal{M}_{1}$ aren't present anymore and all others are selected randomly). Similarly in stage $i$ we select the largest matching $\mathcal{M}_{i}$ which doesn't include any of the edges in $\mathcal{M}_{1}\cup...\cup \mathcal{M}_{i-1}$. Is there a way we can gain some knowledge on the expected size of $\mathcal{M}_{1} \cup...\cup \mathcal{M}_{n}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sudakov and Vu [proved that](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~sudakovb/resilience.pdf), for $p \gg \log n / n$, $G_{n,p}$ has a perfect matching with high probability even after adversarially deleting $(1 - o(1))pn/2$ edges at each vertex.  The same argument works in the bipartite case (and can in fact be slightly simplified).  So for this range of $p$ you expect to be pulling out perfect matchings for at least the first $pn/2$ steps.  In fact, this will still be the case until almost $n/2$ matchings have been removed, as until then it is unlikely that you choose a random graph in which more than half of the edges at any vertex have been used at any previous stage.

Following the comments, here's a slightly more detailed explanation of why we expect to get perfect matchings until around time $n/2$.

At some stage in the process, let $G \sim G_{n,n,p}$ and let $H$ be the subgraph of $K_{n,n}$ consisting of the edges that have already been used.  For each $x \in V(G)$, let $d(x)$ be the degree of $x$ in $G \cap H$.  Let $\epsilon > 0$ and suppose that $n$ is sufficiently large.  We make the following claims.

1. With probability at least $1-\epsilon$, $G$ is such that after deleting any subgraph of maximum degree at most $(1-\epsilon)pn/2$, the remainder $G'$ still has a perfect matching.
2. For each $x \in V(G)$, with probability at least $1-\epsilon/2n$, $d(x) \leq (1+\epsilon)p\Delta(H)$.

The first part is Sudakov and Vu's result.  The second is an easy application of Chernoff's inequality.  It follows by a union bound that, with probablity at least $1-2\epsilon$, $G$ will have a perfect matching even after deleting every edge of $G \cap H$ provided $\Delta(H) < \frac {1-\epsilon} {1+\epsilon} \frac n 2$.

This is enough to tell you that one stage of your process is very likely to succeed, and by iterating that in expectation you will cover close to half of your graph by time $n/2$.  By analysing the failure probabilities more carefully you should be able to show that, with probability tending to $1$ as $n$ tends to infinity, you in fact pull out $(1-\epsilon)n/2$ perfect matchings in the first $(1-\epsilon)n/2$ steps.

Comment: I'm just wondering if this models the same process i was describing, do they take a random graph and then destroy the edges? In my process i'm building a random graph $n$ times, i'm just wondering if their work touches on this idea?

Comment: Could you perhaps explain how i can use their result each time i build a new bipartite graph?

Comment: You take a genuinely random graph then pass to some subgraph.  Sudakov and Vu say that provided you didn't throw away more than half of the edges at any vertex then you have a perfect matching in what's left.  In your case, at each stage you generate a random graph then throw away the edges that have already been used in some matching.  You have to check that this isn't more than half of the edges at any vertex, which it won't be if you have yet to use more than half the edges of $K_{n,n}$.

Comment: Ahh ok this makes sense, so the edges i'm throwing away from my random graph need not be random themselves? I can 'pick' how i'd like to try and break the property but i'd still have no luck if i was breaking less than half of the edges. Is this what you're essentially saying?

Comment: Exactly.  If you throw away random edges then you're really just choosing a slightly smaller random graph in the first place.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help. If you don't mind I was wondering if you could clarify why in this process, we can be pulling perfect matchings out almost to $n/2$ steps? I understand how the result from Sudakov and Vu allows us to pull them out until step $pn/2$ I'm still unclear however how you extended it to almost $n/2$.

Comment: @CBrosen I've added a slightly more detailed explanation to the main answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for the extra detail, just two small questions 1. You said "The second is an easy application of Chernoff's inequality." Chernoff's inequality requires random variables to be independent right? If so how can we use it the degrees of the vertices are not independent random variables. 2. How did you know  "It follows by a union bound that, with probablity at least $1−2\epsilon$, $G$  will have a perfect matching even after deleting every edge of $G \cap H$ provided $\Delta (H)< \frac{1−\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} \frac{n}{2}$?

Comment: The other issue i have with the explanation is you say "With probability at least $1−\epsilon$, $G$ is such that after deleting any subgraph of maximum degree at most $(1−\epsilon)pn/2$, the remainder G′ still has a perfect matching." If however we get close to step $n/2$ still pulling out perfect matchings, then $H$ (at this point) has maximum degree close to $n/2$ which is larger than $(1-\epsilon)pn/2$ so does the first condition not fail?

Comment: The key point is that you aren't deleting all of $H$, you're just deleting a random subgraph of $H$ of density $p$ (the subgraph that happens to intersect $p$).  Everything else is just bookkeeping.

Comment: Ok i'm still not understanding, i want to be crystal clear on what i don't understand, i really appreciate your patience. Let's take some $r=(1-e)n/2$ with $e>0$ (something smaller than n/2) and suppose we get to step $r$, now let $H_{r}$ be the subgraph of all perfect matchings collected so far. Clearly $\Delta(H_{r})=(1-e)n/2$. We are interested in, if the graph $G_{r}\sim G_{n,n,p}$ after removing the edges in $H_{r}$ still has a perfect matching? It seems the degree of each vertex in $G_{r}$ is much less than $n/2$ it's more around $np \ll n/2$ so why couldn't removing $H_{r}$ (continues)

Comment: (continued) not wipe almost all the edges at some vertex in $G_{r}$ meaning there is very little to obtain a perfect matching from?

Comment: one thing i forgot to ask is how do we know the Sudakov and Vu results on $G(n,p)$ still hold on $G_{n,n,p}$ as they are two different random graph models?

Comment: Could the calculations be repeated more or less exactly?

Comment: The first thing Sudakov and Vu do is pass to a bipartite subgraph, so the argument just gets slightly easier.  The paper is freely available and very accessible, so take a look at what they do.

Comment: Ok i will do :)